# Python - Quit program from "While True" loop with mouse click

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop, mouseevent

[Original File](https://github.com/galev00/nmea-Based-Screen/blob/4b270503aa68de84d9791e5d07f9541338986a12/screen8-1.py)

Why i can not CLOSE program WHEN there is a mouse click on a FRAME during WHILE TRUE loop?

Program listens UDP or Sense HAT for input and shows them on a window. it's simple :)

What i want is to exit from program with a **mouseclick**

Final Program will be running on startup and if there is an error it will restart.

Now i will explain my program, you can reach full code from link above. It starts but waits for UDP data. If you want i can upload bat file for server PC to send. *(note: nmea sentences for info only not the ones i get from the boat)*

Finally if you would like to comment structure (or else) of the program Please DO, I haven't written a routine for 30 years. And this my first Python routine.

First Part of program, *(this is short version)*

Import, opens UDP ports and Defines "Close command"

```
import time
try:
    import Tkinter as tk
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *

import socket
UDP_IP_ADDRESS = ""
UDP_PORT_NO = 10110
serverSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSock.bind((UDP_IP_ADDRESS, UDP_PORT_NO))

def rightClick(event): sys.exit()
```

Main Window Design

```
## Main Window
root = Tk()
root.title("Screen GUI")
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry('800x1280-0-0')

## fonts ##
Font208 = ('digiGA2', 156)

awind_frame = Frame(root, bg='cyan', width=800, height=732, pady=0, padx=0)

awind_frame.grid(row=0, sticky="ew")

## create the WIDGETS for the awind_frame
ctr_mid = Frame(awind_frame, bg='black', width=600, height=732)
ctr_mid.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")

## create the WIDGETS for the awind_frame ctr_mid
sog_cer = Frame(ctr_mid, width=600, height=244)
sog_cer.pack_propagate(0)
sog_cer.pack(side = TOP)
sog_label = Label(sog_cer, anchor="e", text='9.9', font=Font208,padx="85", pady="17", bg='black', fg='#ffffff')
```

this where I want sense the "right click"

```
sog_label.bind('<Button-3>', rightClick)
```

and the rest of window

```
sog_label.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

root.update()
```

After these setups while loops starts

```
while True:
   nmea_data, addr = serverSock.recvfrom(1024)
   nmea_header = nmea_data [3:6]
   nmea_data = str(nmea_data)
   def rightClick(event): sys.exit()
```

this part gets nmea data from UDP and sets values to according frames

and EOF is

```
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have found a way to solve the exit problem.

Comment: But `while true` loop is still waiting for an UDP input. How could i make it run without waiting the input?